# Why is replaceChild cause problems?

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-5

```
function httpGet(theUrl) {
  var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlHttp.open("GET", theUrl, false); // false for synchronous request
  xmlHttp.send(null);
  return xmlHttp.responseText;
}

var videosT = httpGet("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&channelId=abcxyz&maxResults=6&order=date&type=video&key=abcxyz");

const videos = JSON.parse(videosT);

for (let step = 0; step < 6; step++) {
  fetch('js/videos.html')
    .then(res => res.text())
    .then(text => {
      let oldelem = document.getElementById("vid_" + step);
      let newelem = document.createElement("div");
      newelem.innerHTML = text;
      oldelem.parentNode.replaceChild(newelem, oldelem);
    })
}
```

html:

```
    <!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Ashk3000</title>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
    integrity="sha384-gH2yIJqKdNHPEq0n4Mqa/HGKIhSkIHeL5AyhkYV8i59U5AR6csBvApHHNl/vI1Bx" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

</head>

<body class="d-flex flex-column" viewport-fit=cover>
  <!-- Navbar -->
  <script id="navbar_placeholder" src="js/nav.js" page="home"></script>

  <!-- Headers -->
  <div
    class="d-none d-lg-block shadow bg-body border border-5 border-top-0 rounded-bottom w-75 position-relative start-50 translate-middle-x mb-5">
    <div class="container-fluid py-5">
      <h1 class="display-5 fw-bold">Home</h1>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="d-lg-none shadow-sm bg-body border-bottom border-5 w-100 position-relative mb-3">
    <div class="container-fluid py-5">
      <h1 class="display-5 fw-bold">Home</h1>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Start -->

  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div id="vid_0"></div>
      <div id="vid_1"></div>
      <div id="vid_2"></div>
      <div class="w-100"></div>
      <div id="vid_3"></div>
      <div id="vid_4"></div>
      <div id="vid_5"></div>
      
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="js/videos.js"></script>

  <!-- Footer -->
  <div class="mt-auto"></div>
  <script id="footer_placeholder" src="js/footer.js"></script>

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-A3rJD856KowSb7dwlZdYEkO39Gagi7vIsF0jrRAoQmDKKtQBHUuLZ9AsSv4jD4Xa"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

videos.html:

```
    <div class="card col" style="width: 18rem;">
  <img src="" id="thumbnail" class="card-img-top" alt="">
  <div class="card-body">
    <h5 id="title" class="card-title">Title</h5>
    <a href="#" id="button" class="btn btn-primary stretched-link">Watch</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hello, I am getting the replit "Not Found" screen when I try this code. I think it has to do with replaceChild. I am new to java script and dont know what it happening. A lot of it is from the internet. I am trying to make it show recent youtube uploads. It wants me to add more text. sorry this is rushed.

Comment: Please add the exact error message to the question.

Comment: `newelem` doesn't have an ID. So the next time this code runs, `document.getElementById('vid_' + step)` won't be able to find the old element.

Comment: Don't use synchronous AJAX. You obviously know how to use `fetch()` and promises, you can get the videos the same way.

Comment: Why are you fetching the same `videos.html` each time through the loop?

Comment: I added video.html

Comment: The only error is on the 
`pic.classList.add('thumbnail_' + step);`
line, because pic does not exist. It should exist with my code though.

Answer (score 0):

When you replace the element, you need to give it the ID of the element that it's replacing, so you will be able to find it the next time.

```
for (let step = 0; step < 6; step++) {
  fetch('js/videos.html')
    .then(res => res.text())
    .then(text => {
      let oldelem = document.getElementById("vid_" + step);
      let newelem = document.createElement("div");
      newelem.id = oldelem.id; // copy the ID.
      newelem.innerHTML = text;
      oldelem.parentNode.replaceChild(newelem, oldelem);
      var pic = document.getElementById('thumbnail');
      pic.classList.add('thumbnail_' + step);
      pic.id = "thumbnail_" + step;
      pic.setAttribute('src', videos.items[step].snippet.thumbnails.high.url);
    })
}
```

Or instead of replacing the element, you could just update the `innerHTML` of the old element.

```
for (let step = 0; step < 6; step++) {
  fetch('js/videos.html')
    .then(res => res.text())
    .then(text => {
      let oldelem = document.getElementById("vid_" + step);
      oldelem.innerHTML = text;
      var pic = document.getElementById('thumbnail');
      pic.classList.add('thumbnail_' + step);
      pic.id = "thumbnail_" + step;
      pic.setAttribute('src', videos.items[step].snippet.thumbnails.high.url);
    })
}
```

Comment: The code should im having trouble with the replacing oldelem. The problem has nothing to do with pic. I should have been more specific. I upated the question.

Comment: My code makes no changes to what you do with `pic`.

Comment: Why do I need to find it again? js/videos.html should include something with the id thumbnail.

Comment: It's not the thumbnail ID, it's the `vid_0`, `vid_1`, etc. ID. I assumed this code is in a function that might be called later to update the page again.